# Always run a specific function in Symfony before saving Entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations, event-listener

I have a Company entity with a one to many relationship with Location. (A Company can have multiple locations).

Location has a boolean "isPrimaryLocation".

Before saving (new/edit) a Location to the database I always want the following logic to be checked:

*Enforce that IF there is a Location for a company, there has to be ONE isPrimaryLocation and maximum ONE location is isPrimaryLocation.*

So my questions:

- Is this something that can be enforced with **Doctrine Annotations**?
- Is this something that I should to do with **LifeCycleCallbacks** and
  PrePersist?
- Is this something that I should to with a **Custom Event and a
  EventListener**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a custom EventListener on prePersist event.